# How do you gateway FlexRay frames before a Graphics/Trace window if you have a CAPL node there?

Tags: gateway, capl, canoe, canalyzer

This is more for practice than anything else. I've added a CAPL node before the graphics window ([Location of CAPL node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eNsM.png)) and I'm just trying to get familiar with doing some simple things like adding offsets to signals and things.

I'm able to pass it through CAN signals untouched if I want to using the following:

```
on message CAN1.*
{
   message CAN1.* msg;
   if(this.dir == rx) {
       msg = this;
       output(msg);
   }
}
```

The problem is that I can't work out how to do this for FlexRay. I've tried a few combinations based on the following but always end up with an error;

```
on frFrame * {
   frFrame * myFrame;

   if(this.dir == rx) {
       myFrame= this;
       output(myFrame);
   }
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error - just no traffic on the other side (in the graphics window in this case). 
I've just tried 'onPDU' and it works. I'm still not sure why on frFrame doesn't though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the FR Frames from the program node to the Graphics window or Trace window, you just have to write the following

```
on frFrame *
{  
  if(this.dir == rx)
    output(this);
}
```

There is no need for adding the condition `if(this.dir == rx)`. Because there is a possibility that the frame is a tx if you are simulating it.